# Detection of zero crossing with false positives

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have this signal as shown in the figure, I have detected several zero-crossings. But some of them are false positives. In reality, the true zero crossings are the ones at 33.15,33.31 and 33.49us. Do you have any idea how I can avoid the detection of the false positives, or at least how can I get rid of them?[image]

Comment: I do not defined them, I know a priori that they are the wrong time instants.

Comment: The other points look like crossings to me. Would be easier to see with a "grid on" though. If your definition of zero crossing depends on that a certain amplitude is reached first you could build a logical of "isLarge=abs(signal)>limit", then loop over your obtained crossings and remove them if your logical does not rise above it before next crossing. I.e. if ~any(IsLarge(idxLastValidCross:idxNextPotentialCross)), remove_next; etc.

Comment: Is it possible to smooth your signal with for example averaging, Then, obtain the the exterma at both sides of a zero point. If their difference becomes greater than a threshold, then you can consider the zero crossing point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first gate the signal area based on prominence of local maxima or minima:

```
prom_threshold = 50; % adjust this value based on the amplitude of your signal.
[~,prom] = islocalmax(signal);
ind = find(prom > prom_threshold);
if numel(ind) < 2
    error('Signal not found');
end
gated_signal = signal(ind(1):ind(end));

% Do your zero crossing algorithm.
```

Read [localmaxima](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/islocalmax.html?s_tid=doc_ta) and [prominence](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/islocalmax.html?s_tid=doc_ta#mw_04336f1d-cc0d-44e8-8a8f-bab26d673ab0).

Comment: I was doing it by calculating the localminimun, but it was too laborious and not intuitive at all. I have a question for you, if I consider the area based on prominence it means that I need to resize the time window right? Because in order to perform my zero-crossing algoritimo I need two signals and the second one is the time signal with same size as the amplitude signal. How do I consider these indexes in the time vector? Best

Comment: @CirugiaoM glad you figured it out. For sake of completeness, here is what I would do. I would do zero crossing algorithm first and use `ind(1)` and `ind(end)` as a validity check: those zero-crossing points with `x` values outside the range bounded by `ind(1)` and `ind(end)`, are false positive.